# Magento coupon code validation

Tags: coupon, validation, coupon-codes

In which file/class, Magento checks if the coupon code is already used by the logged in customer or not?

Comment: what is the magento version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**file** -> `app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php`

**method** -> `protected function _canProcessRule`

Answer (score 1):

It is in app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php

Also you can see the function in 
http://freegento.com/doc/d0/d40/_validator_8php-source.html

```
See the function process() on line 00106
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function process(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item)
```

in app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/model/Validator.php around 297 line